# ссылкgcc - предупреждение: неявное объявление функции 'get_int'

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cs50

Я делаю курс CS50 и решил запустить код оттуда на моем компьютере.

Вот мой код:

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        //gets an integer from a user
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n * 2 + 2; j++)
        {
            //prints hashes only if j is more or equal to n - 1 
            if (j >= n - i && j <= n - 1)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            //prints empty spaces to make the pyromide right alinged
            else if (j <= n - i)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            //makes empty spaces between two pyromids
            else if (j >= n - 1 && j <= n + 1)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            //adds hashes for the second pyromid
            else if (j >= n + 2 && j <= n + 1 + i)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

        }
        //starts a new line after finishing the code
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

И когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать это, происходит следующее:

```
gcc cs50.o mario.c -o mario.exe -std=c99 -lcs50
mario.c: In function 'main':
mario.c:10:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_int' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         n = get_int("Height: ");
         ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcs50
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Я пытался запустить код из модуля cs50 на моем компьютере под ос Windows 10 с помощью компилятора gcc, и у меня появляется эта ошибка. Сначала я попытался создать промежуточный файл из cs50.c и cs50.h, используя эту строку: `gcc -c cs50.c` // создал объект с именем cs50.o, который тоже не помог . Также я пробовал связать библиотеку cs50 этим `-lcs50`  но это тоже ничего не дало.

Вот методы, которые я использовал:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214170/importing-c-library-in-windows/15234362#15234362

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432721/how-to-link-the-cs50-c-library-in-gcc-on-windows/57439227#57439227

ссылка на библеотеку cs50 : https://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/

Comment: В заголовках `int GetInt(void);` а вы пишете `get_int(char const *)`. Где вы такую функцию нашли?

Comment: @AlexGlebe cs50.c это такая мини библиотека курса в которой и должен быть этот метод

Comment: Значит библиотека не подключена. Попробуйте добавить ключ `-Lполный_путь_к_каталогу_библиотек`. Чтобы там библиотеку gcc искал.

Comment: 1) Вы должны использовать функцию `GetInt`, а не `get_int`. 2) Можете просто скомпилировать `cs50.c` вместе со своим исходным файлом: `gcc mario.c cs50.c -o mario.exe -std=c99`

Comment: Этот cs50 начинается с рассказа о порядке компиляции программ, нет?